# How to use a background image in a div?

Tags: html, css, image

I am having trouble adding an image to a div. I have both the file and the image in the same folder and the image is a jpg. I have also tried putting the online image link (http://www.aussieinfrance.com/wp-content/uploads/stockholm-4.jpg) in with no success. Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
       <body>
            <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a class="active" href=“#home”>Sweden</a>
  <a href=“government.html”>Government</a>
  <a href=“borders.html”>Borders</a>
  <a href="#about">Iconography</a>
</div>
<div class="overview" id="overview">
<p>Sweden is a northern country that specializes in trading machinery, paper products, and iron and steel products</p>
</div>
</body>
</html
```

and here is my css file:

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #262228;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    font-family: verdana;
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 27px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 19px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #FFCE00;
    color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: verdana;
}

.overview p {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 550px;
    color: #262228;
    text-align: right;
}

.overview {
      background-image: url(“stockholm.jpg”);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use plain quotes `"` instead of typographic quotes `“”` in the CSS `url` directive.
2. In CSS a path to an image is specified relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file. So make sure that the image is in the same folder with the CSS file.
3. Try to use `./stockholm.jpg` instead of `stockholm.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

The Image Your Referenced Is It On The Same Directory Where the style.css file Located. If not then specify the path relative path of the image like `background-image: url('./img/stockholm.jpg');` (if the file is on the img folder). See the relative and absolute file path declaration to understand. Hope it helps. Thank you.